# fragment not shown on top in activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

i want to show a fragment when i click a item into my action bar, in code i do that:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.create_boundary:
                Fragment boundary = new BoundaryFragment();
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.map_activity, boundary);
                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
             break;
        }
    }
```

and the fragment:

```
public class BoundaryFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // create the view of the fragment associate with the maps activity
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.boundary_maps, container, false);
        return view;
    }
```

fragment's layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</GridLayout>
```

activity_map.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:id="@+id/map_activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

onCreate of mapsActivity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        [...]
       }
```

i don't understand why is not shown.Can someone tell me what's is wrong?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the xml code relative to the R.id.map_activity id?

Comment: @valbertos just done.

Comment: @valbertos what's wrong in your opinion?

Comment: you explicitely tie fragment to a class in your `<fragment>`. try replacing `<fragment>` with `<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/map_activity" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" />`

Comment: @AlexanderZhak, thanks for the comment, can you explain me why i have to make this change?

Comment: Do you need to add the new fragment on top of the other one or to replace it completely?

Comment: Please take a look at Fragments Design Phylosophy. It might help you http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the official documentation for [FragmentTransaction.replace(int,Fragment,String)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace(int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String)):

> **Parameters**
>   - **`containerViewId`**   Identifier of the container whose
>   fragment(s) are to be replaced.
>   - **`fragment`**  The new fragment to place in
>   the container.
>   - **`tag`**   Optional tag name for the fragment, to later
>   retrieve the fragment with `FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(String)`.

That means you are using the `id` in the transaction incorrectly. Also you may want to add the `BoundaryFragment` on top of the one defined in the XML layout, therefore you should use [FragmentTrasaction.add(int, Fragment)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add(int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String)) instead.

To fix your problem anyway you should move your `id` to the `RelativeLayout`, as below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map_activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <fragment android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You probably want to put the BoundaryFragment on top of the other. Therefore you should use `FragmentTransaction.add()` rather than `.replace()`

Comment: well i want to do that.

Comment: i made a lot of test, but they all failed.Because if i put the `android:id="@+id/map_activity` inside relativeLayout , the `onCreate` method of the activity crashes because it can't find the id.acitivty_map causes a `nullPointExecption` , so i have to insert the id into `fragment tag` , it is the only way to load the `activity_map` layout , but in this way i cant add o replace the new fragment.

Comment: The NPE is a symptom that you are using the id somewhere in your activity to get the map fragment. Just define another id on your RelativeLayout and use that in your transaction.

Comment: with two id, doens't work anyway. see question update to see new xml.

Comment: I think you are messing a little too much with your code now. Leave ```@+id/map_activity``` in your ```<fragment />``` tag. Add ```@+id/fragment_container``` to your ```<RelativeLayout>``` and use the same id in your transaction, ie: ```.add(R.id.fragment_container, boundary)```

Answer (score 1):

First, you are using a Fragment as it would be a ViewGroup. You’re trying to place a Fragment inside another Fragment when you perform the next statement:

```
ft.replace(R.id.map_activity, boundary);
```

Second, you can’t replace a fragment that has been defined in the layout file. You can only replace fragments that you added dynamically using FragmentTransaction.

To achieve what you want, [take a look](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) at the sample code under the section: 
"Or, programmatically add the fragment to an existing ViewGroup."